# Best Practice for Binding ItemsControl in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What is the best practice for binding a list of items to an ItemsControl when using the MVVM pattern?

### 1. Bind a list of ViewModels

Load the items from the database, create the models and all viewmodels and then bind a list of viewmodels to the ItemsControl.ItemsSource:

```
public class MyMainViewModel
{
    public List<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

### 2. Bind a list of Models

Load the items from the database, create the models and then bind a list of those models directly to the ItemsControl.ItemsSource:

```
public class MyMainViewModel
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do note that in option 2, if `Person` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` it can cause a memory leak. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here is really *it depends*.

Firstly, you need to assess whether your view needs to *interact* with your model in such a way that it would make sense for a view model to be *wrapped around* a particular model. Let's look at an example:

```
public class WebsiteModel
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

Here I have a very simple model which represents a website, nothing too fancy. I can create a view model which will encompass all websites, like a one to many relationship:

```
public class WebsitesViewModel
{
    //A list of websites.
    public List<WebsiteModel> Websites { get; set; }

    //The command I will use to navigate, where the object parameter will be the WebsiteModel.
    public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; set; }

    ...

    public void Navigate(WebsiteModel model)
    {  
       ...
}
```

Here I want my view to be able to **navigate** to the URL using the browser. My view model holds a list of models and my command takes care of navigation.

The next method I can create a view model to represent a **single** model, I would say this is a SOLID approach:

```
public class WebsiteViewModel
{
    //The website model
    public WebsiteModel Website { get; set; }

    //The command I will use to navigate, no parameters needed.
    public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; set; }

    ...

    public void Navigate()
    {  
       ...
}
```

In this scenario, I'll need another view model which will expose a list of `WebsiteViewModel` to my view.

```
public List<WebsiteViewModel> Websites { get; set; }
```

The truth is there isn't really a *best practice*. Neither method really trumps the other. There are benefits to each method, however the method to choose really depends on the implementation. In this scenario, method 2, I would say is overcomplicated. However it's not uncommon for a view model to become very large very quickly, and the need to separate concerns will force you to create smaller classes, and even view models to wrap your models inside, making method 2 a viable option.

So to wrap up. Neither method is *best practice*.

Answer (score 0):

The only "correct" way to do it, is to use ViewModels all the way.

While initially more work, it gives you more flexibility and less bugs later on.

Don't for get, when you a model should only be valid in it's bounded context and when you bind your ViewModel to the view, you have a leaky abstraction. The View becomes aware of model and each change to the model, will affect your View.

Further more, refactoring doesn't work within XAML. So if you name a model property via refactoring, your XAML will still bind to the old property. This doesn't give you a compile error and your bounded element will just remain empty (in best case) or crash (in worst case).

This can be quite hard to figure out and fix. Also as Scroog1 commented, it introduces memory leaks. May not be noticeable in small applications, but ones working with big data sets it can lead to out of memory exceptions.

You should utilize an automapping library to map from Model to ViewModel in cases that allows it, this will reduce some boilerplate code. But remember to avoid ViewModel to Model automappings, as it's discouraged.

You want to avoid that a change in your model influences code in a different bounded context, i.e. you don't want to expose every database or model change in a rest service, even if the change do not influence the given rest action.

The same strategy can be applied to the n-layer model (View, ViewModel, (Domain) Model layer, Services and Infrastructure)

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no correct way, using models is the pragmatic and simpler way, using view models is more time consuming but more decoupled...

You should have a look at this article: 
http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx

also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61147/MVVM-Creating-ViewModel-Wrap-your-business-object